# Why is .$el needed, and what does it point to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

This is probably more of a javascript question, but I'm going through this backbone tutorial and was wondering why is there a .$el at the end of this line, and which element is it point to?

```
self.$el.append((new BlogView({ model: blog})).render().$el);
```

Here is the full code below.....

```
var BlogsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: blogs, 
    el: $('.blogs-list'),
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('add', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.$el.html('');
        _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(blog) {
            self.$el.append((new BlogView({ model: blog})).render().$el);
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: We can only assume that `new BlogView({ model: blog})).render()` returns an object with a `$el` property that is a DOM node, and that node should be appended to `self.$el`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$el` is a reference for the DOM element for the view. Backbone views are not DOM elements themselves, they are generic javascript objects which have a property called `$el` which holds the DOM element which is what you actually see on the webpage. You can think of a backbone view as a controller of sorts for the DOM element, and when you add event listeners to your view, define render, etc, you are always acting on its DOM element stored in `$el` (`$el` is the same DOM element as `el`, the former just plays nicely with jQuery). In this case, your view is `BlogView` and if we break `new BlogView({ model: blog})).render().$el` up:

- `new BlogView` - creating an instance of your view, backbone will automatically create a DOM element for your view and store it in `yourView.$el`
- `.render()` - telling the view to render its HTML inside the `$el` element. In Backbone, our render function is where we generate HTML markup/format data and "draw" the view by shoving this markup into our view's `$el`.
- `render().$el` - `render()` returns `this` which is just our view itself, so calling `render().$el` is like saying "render my view and return my DOM element.
- `self.$el.append(..)` - this block of code is thus given our DOM element `$el` which then inserts it.

so putting it all together we get: `new BlogView({ model: blog})).render().$el` which first creates our view, renders our view and returns our view's DOM element which can be appended to the page, manipulated, etc.

Comment: Completely different question.. In ""new BlogView({ model: blog})).render().$el"", what's the point of not having render() run automatically?... you said it first creates our view, then renders our view... why did they decide to do them separately instead of just all in one shot......

Comment: Great answer by the way... helped me understand it